# Visual Basic e.SuppressKeyPress Does Not Work When Clicking a Button with Button.PerformClick()

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make my program press a button in the form if the "enter" key is pressed while in a specific text box.

I have used similar code to change focus between text boxes, and it works perfectly fine.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

In this instance, the Windows noise does not play, and the focus is changed from TextBox1 to TextBox2.

However, I tried to implement the same code while only changing one line.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        Button2.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

The "e.SuppressKeyPress = True" does not stop the Windows noise from playing.

I have researched this for about three hours now, and have come up empty handed multiple times. I have tried setting the button to the default "AcceptButton", but then when I press enter in ANY text box, then the button is pressed. I only want the button to be pressed if enter is pressed in TextBox2.

I should also mention, simply pressing the button does not make the noise. Only if the user presses "enter" in TextBox2.

EDIT 1 - I have tried to debug as best I can, and it appears to only be happening when the user presses enter.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Removing the button click from the code (see above) makes the Windows noise stop. I'm completely at a loss here...

Comment: This is off the top of my head but what if you set `e.Handled` to `True`?

Comment: e.Handled (from what I understand) should only be used in KeyPress. Not KeyDown. Someone can correct me if I am wrong. And, I believe I have tried putting both already.

Comment: By the way, the documentation clearly states that an application developer should call `Select` rather than `Focus`. Sometimes it makes no difference but other times it does. If you call `Select` then you don't have to know which are which.

Comment: Thank you. I will change over to Select instead of Focus.

Comment: Maybe it's used more on the `KeyPress` event but I've never heard that it shouldn't be used on `KeyDown`.

Comment: I just tested 3 variations.
e.Handled alone does not stop the sound from playing.
e.Handled and e.SuppressKeyPress together does not stop the sound from playing.
e.SuppressKeyPress alone does not stop the sound from playing.

Comment: A better answer is not to call `PerformClick`.  Instead, refactor the code that occurs in the button click handler out into a separate method and then call that method from both the button click handler and from the `TextBox2.KeyDown` method.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing`Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown` to `Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress`and only using `e.Handled = true`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Performclick command sends your code off the scope of the keydown command, it is processed as a key event nested into a key event, as a SendKeys.SendWait{F6} command in this same context would, for example.
In other words, it's like you need to call SuppressKeyPress another time. I don't know how to do that.